# Strange behavior in reputation system?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

I'm witnessing some strange behavior in regards to my reputation. One hour ago, my reputation was at 18,950 points. Then I answered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394648/how-to-convert-json-file-to-arrayliststring/36394672#36394672) (fairly trivial) question and the following happened:

- It got upvoted twice, but my reputation *dropped* by 4 points, as if it were downvoted twice. Reputation was suddenly at 18,946 points.
- It got upvoted a third time. Reputation rose by 10 points (correct), and then it was accepted and reputation rose by 15 points (correct). It is now at 18,971, while by my count it should be at 18,995.

To note:

- The original upvotes are correctly reported in the [reputation tab of my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen?tab=reputation).
- There is no mention of me losing reputation due to a user being deleted or any other reason.

I don't care all that much about the points, but the inexplicable behavior bugs me. Is this a bug, or am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong. You can also look at: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ ?

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks, didn't know about that. The numbers I see there do not correspond to the numbers I've been seeing in any of my browsers, nor my smartphone app.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen So if the numbers from the `/reputation` page and your reputation tab doesn't line up, I bet either caching or something got messed up and your rep just needs to be recalculated. But I bet for the first one.

Comment: Incidentally, I believe there are some ways in which reputation can disappear without a "user removed" or similar mark. I think the rep I earned on a tag-wiki edit for a tag that was later deleted vanished without a trace. I don't know for sure if that was the cause though, no good way to reproduce, especially since I'm past the review threshold now.

Comment: About the caching: how could it be cached at 18,950 points, and then drop to 18,946 without any negative event since Feb 24?

Comment: Or try a full rep export listing like [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation)

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, I've looked at that. See the comments above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you tick the "show removed posts" checkbox in the [reputation tab of your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3558960/robby-cornelissen?tab=reputation) (at the bottom of the page), you will see that a user was removed around that time, with their posts. All associated reputation given from this user has gone.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that. So, the user that posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097220/how-to-seperate-words-using-comma-in-php/25097239#25097239) was removed. Is that the policy then? To also remove all the user's questions along with all the answers that were given to those questions? Not that any earth-shattering revelations will now lay forever hidden from mankind in this particular case, but still...

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - a question without any upvotes, yeah. We are trying to get a collection of *good* questions and answers, and this one... fell short.

Comment: Yeah, no argument there.